# C# P/Invoke with Variants

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Anybody know what my DLLImport statement should look like here:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) long SomeFunction(VARIANT *argNames, VARIANT *argValues, VARIANT *pVal)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variant is an object.

> **Type Conversions**

> During marshaling one of the most important steps is
> converting unmanaged types to managed types and vice versa.The CLR
> marshaling service knows how to perform many of these conversions for
> you, but you must still know how the various types match up to each
> other when converting the unmanaged signature to the managed function.
> You can use this conversion table to match up the various types.

> **Table 1**

```
+-------------------------+------------------+  
|    Windows Data Type    |  .NET Data Type  |  
+-------------------------+------------------+  
| VARIANT                 |  Object          |  
+-------------------------+------------------+
```

From documentation downloaded from here (page 9,249):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Broken link. :-(

Comment: @Dave: Well, no. The link is intact, it just takes you to the archived documentation. Which you can read and get the information that was formerly directly linked. I edited the answer to include the relevant part of the documentation for those that may not have the time or desire to read on their own.